# Using biblatex for footcites / footcite no reference to .bib file

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to use footcite. The problem is, that in the footcite it self it doesn't use the informations from the .bib file.

From my file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\bibliography{Master}

\author{xx}

\begin{document}

\include{./Titelseite}

\tableofcontents

\include{./Kap_1}
%\include{./Kap_2}
%\include{./Kap_3}
%\include{./Kap_4}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Master.bib:

```
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
```

Kap_01:

```
\section{Intro}
Blabla.\footcite{A01}
```

The output I get is a footcite^1 but in the bottom of the page there stands no informations about the book but rather just A01 and nothing else. Also using styles like `style=mla`  `style=authordate` does not change anything.

Also it doesn't print the bibliography. Why?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: did you run biber after running latex?

Comment: Whats biber? I use pdflatex biblatex pdflatex2x

Comment: `biber` is the `bibtex` replacement used by `biblatex`.  It is possible to use `bibtex` (as far as I know no utility called `biblatex` exists) you have to use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, and then run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`x2.